# SharePoint 2016 Morning error: There has been an error while loading form

Tags: 2016

When my users come in and their browser is sitting on a page that they had used the evening before and the page requires another input (like a sign-in, sign-out setup), the user is presented with a SharePoint error that there has been an error loading the form.
Other than initially refreshing the page or closing the browser from the night before, is there a way, like keep-alives for instance, to allow the user from using a "stale" page?

Wiley Winter